# Ideal Reconstruction of Upsampled Signal

Tags: sampling, interpolation, reconstruction

**Problem**: The signal $cos(2\pi14100t)$ is sampled at $F_s = 400 Hz$. It is then upsampled with a factor 3 and then reconstructed ideally with a new frequency $F = 500 Hz$.

I now want to find the new signal that is created.

**Incomplete solution**: With the frequency before sampling $\pm 141000 Hz$. After sampling the normalized frequencies:

$f = \pm {14100 \above 1 pt 400} \pm k = \pm (35 + {1 \above 1 pt 4})\pm k= \pm {1 \above 1 pt 4} \pm k $ per sample

Interpolation with factor 3 yields the normalized frequencies:

$f = {\pm {1 \above 1 pt 4} \pm k \above 1 pt 3} = $ 3 frequencies $\pm k?$

I know how to solve it past that to get the final $F= \pm f * F_s$. I.e. $y(t) = cos(2\pi f_1t) + cos(2\pi f_2t) + cos(2\pi f_3t)$.

**So my question is how do I calculate the 3 frequencies?** Would greatly appreciate a simple solution and not just an answer so that I actually understand this.

Comment: there are so many things wrong with this question that there is little that can be done with it.

Comment: Took most of it from a text book. With a given problem and partial solution given, so a bit surprised by it being that unsalvageable. But guess I probably translated or presented it incorrectly. 
Either way I think the original problem description is small and straight-forward enough that any issues with it can be pointed out or even just provided a complete solution like the answer I was given.

Comment: so you don't see a problem sampling a 14100 Hz sinusoid at a sample rate of 400 Hz?

Comment: For a real-life application I would imagine this could be a problem. This is however just an educational problem created for students to understand upsampling, downsampling and reconstruction of signals.

Comment: this is not about "upsampling" or "downsampling".  it is about **under-sampling**.  it's about reconstructing an undersampled signal.  why doesn't the Nyquist/Shannon sampling theorem apply here?  are you assuming that you **know** it's a single sinusoid in a particular frequency range?  without assumptions like that, you have no hope of reconstructing the signal.

Comment: Sorry, that was exactly the point I was trying to make. Under-sampling doesn't matter exactly because this is just a problem to be solved in a textbook. It is is only the method of reconstruction itself that is being examined in this particular problem and not whether doing so will prove very meaningful. To its credit such things are discussed and dealt with later in this particular textbook. Though I could see meaning in thinking in such terms from the very start (since it's essential) I could also see some threat of it overcomplicating things at the very start when going through the basics.

Comment: Should perhaps stress that "ideally reconstruct" is the name of the method they wanted you to use and not the goal. I very likely translated that incorrectly from Swedish.

Comment: you cannot ideally reconstruct that signal with the standard $$ x(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(nT) \frac{\sin\left(\pi \frac{t-nT}{T} \right)}{\pi \frac{t-nT}{T}} $$ reconstruction formula because $T\triangleq\frac{1}{F_s}$ is way too large because $F_s$ is way too small.  you *could* with a lot of assumptions regarding prior knowledge of the signal (like its frequency range is restricted to a **very** small band of frequencies) possibly reconstruct.  is your question about deriving a well-defined expression of that restriction?

Comment: I checked the questions again. And confirmed that it was written as stated and only other thing written was "Signals are sampled, down sampled or up-sampled and reconstructed ideally according to the items below. Determine what the resulting signal will be" as the title instructions to these particular line of questions. I'm not sure I can answer any of your doubts more than I have. I think it's simply to test students ability to mechanically apply 2-3 mathematical algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the question and your description.

When we sample a signal of frequency $f_m$ with a sampling rate $f_s$, the sampled signal contains the frequencies $f=f_m \pm nf_s$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.
Here the frequencies available in the sampled signal are calculated as,

$f_m=14100 Hz$
 and $f_s=400 Hz$.
we know that,

$ f=f_m \pm nf_s $, where $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, ... $

ie., $ f= ..., -1500, -1100, -700, -300, 100, 500, 900, 1300, 1700, ... $

When we up sample the signal by 3, the frequencies will become $f/3$.

So here the new frequencies are, $ f_u = ..., -633.33, -500, -366.67, -233.33, -100, 33.33, 166.67, 300, 433.33, 566.67, ... $

After upsampling the signal is reconstructed by using an LPF of cutoff frequency 500.
When we apply LPF to the above signal only the frequencies whose absolute value is below 500 remains and other frequencies will loss.

there for after applying LPF the frequency components available in the signal are,  $ -500, -366.67, -233.33, -100, 33.33, 166.67, 300, 433.33 $.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes thank you. Solved it through other means and ended up forgetting this, sorry for the late confirmation.